# How to load .bashrc when using wsl interoperability?

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim

I've downloaded neovim 5.1 and made a symlink to it in .local/bin folder.
After that I've added it to $PATH through .bashrc and aliased to vim:

```
alias vim="nvim"
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

If I use `vim` command from inside the wsl I successfully launch neovim 5.1. However if I instead try to launch vim from powershell (`wsl vim`) .bashrc is ignored and vim 8.1 is launched instead. How can I make Powershell to use .bashrc in interoperability mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wsl bash -ic vim
```

- `-i` tells `bash` that the shell is interactive, which causes `~/.bashrc` to be loaded.
- `-c` cause the next argument to be executed as a command(s); it also causes the `bash` process to exit after command execution.